# How to check for an empty Map in a Soy template?

Tags: google-closure-templates, soy-templates

I've read the [docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/overview) for Google Soy/Closure templates, but can't find any way to check whether a Map is empty; I can only look up the map's value for a given key. Is there a way to find out the size of a Map?

My current workaround is to replace any empty maps with `null` and then check for `null` in the template, e.g.:

```
{if $myMap}
    <!-- Do something that requires a non-empty map -->
{/if}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the keys of the map using the `keys` function, and then use `length` on that, so this should work:

```
{if length(keys($myMap)) == 0}
   ...
{/if}
```